# Updating a NETCore app to an AspNetCore app

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2019, service-fabric-stateful

I originally created a simple Microsoft NETCore stateful service, but am trying to use a library that requires it to be an AspNetCore service. Is there any way I can update the existing service to AspNetCore without deleting it and creating a new one?

I've tried simply installing the asp nugets. Sorry, I'm a little new to visual studio and service fabric applications.

Comment: You could create a ASP.NET core app using new project template and compare what's inside the project files.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what a "Net Core Stateful Service" is - but, to convert an app to be an ASP Core service, you need to change the csProj file so the Project section looks like this:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
   
     <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
      </PropertyGroup>

     <Your stuff here>

</Project>
```